# User control that can hover and can be attached to form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When I moves window on screen, user control is not moving.Is there any way we can add the control to the window except we create control at run time in form window. I have shared the code below.

I've created a custom CustomBox using links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353561/how-to-create-a-c-sharp-winforms-control-that-hovers#354326) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398176/listbox-with-overriden-createparams-doesnt-raise-item-events#398694)

User Control Code

```
Private mList As CustomBox
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  
       mList = New CustomBox(Me)
       mList.Location = New Point(5, 10)
       mList.Size = New Size(50, Me.ClientSize.Height + 50)
        
       For ix As Integer = 0 To 100 - 1
            mList.Items.Add(ix)
       Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: No there isn't. Controls that can display outside of a form, e.g. `ComboBox` and `DateTimePicker`, create separate windows for their drop-downs internally.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353561/how-to-create-a-c-sharp-winforms-control-that-hovers#354326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

Instead of passing `Me` (i.e. user control instance) as parent, pass the `Me.ParentForm` as the parent. In case you still require the user control instance for any other purpose, just pass it as another parameter.

The other thing you need to manage is the offset. For that you can simply add the user control's location to wherever you want to place it.

Here is the updated code:

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Private mList As CustomBox

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        mList = New CustomBox(Me.ParentForm)
        mList.Location = Me.Location + (New Point(5, 10))
        mList.Size = New Size(50, Me.ClientSize.Height + 50)

        For ix As Integer = 0 To 100 - 1
            mList.Items.Add(ix)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's how it looks with above code changes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGb78.jpg

Comment: I tried your solution it will not work .. if we set the above property .pop up control will not be display on the window .

Comment: Are you looking for a form inside a form sort of thing?

Comment: Yes kind of   ..In that case parent windoe will loose the focus. .. @Pradeep

Comment: I still don't get what you need. Are you looking for a control that can be placed outside the form window area?

Comment: Please check the attached image. using above code I am getting expected output but when I move the window user control is not moving.

Comment: I copied and pasted your exact same code and it works as expected. i.e. control moves with the form. Check here: https://imgur.com/a/D80JsXk

Comment: You are using form so it's working. But I want to use code in user control. Use usercontrol instead of form

Comment: ohh..ok.. Now I get what you mean.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Check whether this is what you are looking for.