# Paint out of window (and controls)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, window, drawing

I think that if I use image it would be best:
[image]

I need that my control could be out of window as datetimepicker calendar. I am using `panelKalendar = new PanelDoubleBuffer();` then in method: `void panelKalendar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)` I paint everything. But it´s painting to window and belov all other controls. How can I get "effect" that is use in DateTimePicker?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control extending beyond border of parent control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833683/control-extending-beyond-border-of-parent-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drop-down list of a combo box (and also possibly the drop-down panel of a calendar control) is a child window of the desktop. That's what you also have to do: nest your control inside a borderless form, and give that form a null parent, so that it is a top-level window, not a child of your application window.

Since your form will be a top-level window, its location will need to be specified in screen coordinates, not in coordinates local to your form. You can get those coordinates using the `PointToScreen` method.

Comment: You don't want a child window at all! That's the problem, you want a top-level window. [Don't confuse parents and owners](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/15/9978691.aspx).

Comment: @CodyGray Wait, I may be wrong of course, but please explain to me: when we say 'child of the desktop' don't we mean a window which was created with a NULL parent? And isn't this the same as to say top-level window?

Comment: That might be what some people mean when they say it, but it's not how I would interpret it. A child window of the desktop would literally be a window that has the desktop window as its parent, such as a top-level window on which you called `SetParent` and specified the desktop window. And such a situation would be lethal the minute you called something like `MessageBox` to show a modal dialog.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification. Now, what would you say is the drop-down list of a combo box? Is it a child of the desktop, or is it a top-level window?

Comment: The confusion might be in the terminology of a "`NULL` parent". If you call `CreateWindow` (or `CreateWindowEx`) and specify `NULL` for the `hWndParent` parameter, you're not actually creating an owned window. That means "create this window without an owner". It's how you create top-level windows. All windows are descendants of the desktop, but that doesn't mean they are it's children.

Comment: @CodyGray You know, I have been programming Windows since 3.11, and I have always known that there is this complication with owned windows and child windows, and yet I never managed to find a clear enough answer so as to fully, completely understand precisely how this thing works. I have just always managed to do my work either avoiding the issue, or by trial and error. (Horrible, I know.) I will look for some online text to read up on it. But my immediate need is to edit my answer so as not to be saying something which is not true. So, what would you say should be reworded in my answer?

Comment: Yes, it's a confusing issue, and I don't understand it as completely as I probably should, either. You have the right idea. The solution is to create a new (probably borderless) top-level window and show that in response to the drop-down event. It's just the part about "making it a child form of the desktop" that's wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray Okay, I reworded it. I hope it is better now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't achieve what you want with the *child* control of your `form` (that is what you're doing actually), cause it will be truncated by the parent (`form`) bounds.

Imo, you can try to use a seprate `WidnowdForm` control, that appears *exactly* in the place where the `panel` appears now.

Hope this helps.