# Hiding form when are other controls focus

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2008, focus

This question is related to [this my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836255/paint-out-of-window-and-controls). Now I have form in my class and when user click on button I show (or hide) form. That´s ok. But I want to hide form when I move with origin form or when I click somewhere in origin form. The new form is behind that origin form. I was trying events like lostfocus and others but It didn´t help. So I think I need some trick that check from my control if there was click in parrent form (origin form) or some other hack. I know the best would be that I put code but I have many lines so I think that best way will be if you help me in general way and then I try to applicate to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a global mouse and keyboard [hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In fact, its been wrapped up into well documented, well structured .NET API over at [CodePlex](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/)

Go over there and download it. Then, set up a global mouse hook:

```
    _mouseListener = new MouseHookListener(new GlobalHooker());
    _mouseListener.MouseMove += HandleGlobalHookMouseMove;
    _mouseListener.Start();
```

The key here is that you will receive the MouseMove event ANY time the mouse moves ANYWHERE on the desktop, not just within the bounds of your window.

```
 private void HandleAppHookMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {

        if (this.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
        {
              HandleEnter();
        }
        else
        {
              HandleLeave();
        }          
  }
```

You can also setup one for `MouseClick`. The combination of the two will enable you to determine any time the mouse moves over your origin form, or the mouse is clicked when its over it. Unlike the `LostFocus` and other events you tried, focus is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Does below help?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form f2 = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location) && f2.Visible) { f2.Hide(); }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2.Visible = !f2.Visible ? true : false;
    }
}
```