# Issues with Windows forms user control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I am creating a Windows forms user control. This control has a `textbox` and a `listbox`.

When the end user types text in the `textbox`, the listbox will appear and filter the data 
depending on the text box. The data is set by a datasource.

I have created this control because I want to filter in the contains of data "not start with."

Now after I create the control I found a problem when the list appear it did not appear out of form boundaries.

I change the control size in appear and disappear the listbox. What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control extending beyond border of parent control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833683/control-extending-beyond-border-of-parent-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not show a `ListBox` out of the boundaries of its parent `Form`. What you really wan to do is open a *new* `Form` where `ListBox` is visible.

Hope this helps.