# How can I prevent a form from stealing focus while still receiving mouse clicks?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm attempting to create a custom AutoCompleteTextBox control in WinForms. The AutoComplete provided by the basic TextBox provides results only with `(string).StartsWith` as opposed to `(string).Contains`.

I am displaying the Auto-Complete search results in a `ListBox` docked in a separate `Form`. I can prevent the `Form` from stealing focus initially using via:

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
   get { return true; }
}
```

Then, I can prevent the `Form` from gaining focus entirely by overriding the `WndProc` method via:

```
protected override void WndProc( ref Message m )
{
    base.WndProc( ref m );
    switch ( m.Msg )
    {
        case WM_MOUSEACTIVATE:
            m.Result = ( IntPtr ) MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

When I do this, the `ListBox` contained in the `Form` will receive `MouseMoved` events, but not `MouseClicked` events.

Chaning `MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT` to just `MA_NOACTIVATE` will pass the mouse events to the `ListBox`, but then will cause the clicks on the `ListBox` to steal focus from the `Form` the `ListBox` resides in - passing it to the 'floating' `Form` the `ListBox` is in.

Is there any way I can prevent the 'floating' `Form` from steeling focus from the 'main' `Form` while still getting `MouseClick` events within the `ListBox`?

Comment: I think you will simply be forced to put focus back on the main form after the click is received in the list box ...or you use the mouse move event to determine which list box item is being hovered over. The HitTest (IIRC) will give you a ListBoxItem.

Comment: @lAbstract The problem with shifting focus back is that it will cause the main form to then appear in front of the floating form the next time you want to show the floating form. Then calling BringToFront on the floating form gives it focus - stealing it from the main form again.

Comment: ...ah, understood: so, if you are able to monitor the mouse moves from your main form, are you able to get `HitTestInfo` on your main form? If you can do that, then you can actually receive the selected item from the floating form ...I think. ;)

Comment: This assumes the main form is responsible for such things. This is a custom control class which will be used in multiple other forms - so that is a little infeasable from a re-use point of view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a C# Winforms Control that hovers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353561/how-to-create-a-c-sharp-winforms-control-that-hovers)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your floating form into a `Usercontrol` as below :-
Pull a ListBox on it to & hook onto Click event to simulate your scenario of Focus.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class InactiveForm : UserControl
    {
        private const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
        private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
        private const int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008;


        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern int SetParent
         (IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern int ShowWindow
         (IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);


        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {

                CreateParams p = base.CreateParams;
                p.ExStyle |= (WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST);
                p.Parent = IntPtr.Zero;
                return p;
            }
        }

        public InactiveForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public new void Show()
        {
            if (this.Handle == IntPtr.Zero) base.CreateControl();

            SetParent(base.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);
            ShowWindow(base.Handle, 1);
        }


        private void OnListBoxClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked List Box on floating control");

        }
    }
}
```

**Code in the MainForm (with a button and its click handler attached):-**

This invokes the floating control with ListBox.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InactiveForm f = new InactiveForm();
             f.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

When you show the UserControl (borderless form) as your floating form, you will notice that `it wont receive focus even if you clicked (selected) any of its children`. In this case, the child is a ListBox on the usercontrol.

Refer [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?469933-Adding-NoActivate-to-a-New-Form) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3f1c4191-38f4-4d15-a633-9f57cff289e4/).

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to previous answer by Angshuman Agarwal:
If you want the main form does not deactive when the UserControl show as floating form, modify some code to your UserControl:

```
private Control _mControl;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public new void Show(Control c)
{
    if (c == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    _mControl = c;
    if (this.Handle == IntPtr.Zero) base.CreateControl();
    SetParent(base.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);
    ShowWindow(base.Handle, 1);
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x86)  //WM_NCACTIVATE
    {
        if (m.WParam != IntPtr.Zero) //activate
        {
            SendMessage(_mControl.Handle, 0x86, (IntPtr)1, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        this.DefWndProc(ref m);
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created something similiar and my solution is similar to what lAbstract suggests. The floatin form has an event DoReturnFocus wich the custom TextBox (the AutoCompleteTextBox control in this case) subscribes to, and simply sets focus back to itself. To prevent the main form to appear in front of the floating form I set the main form as the **Owner** of the floating form, as owned forms are never displayed behind their owner form..

More on [Form.Owner Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)