# ToolStripDropDown with no bounds constraint

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

I am using ToolStripDropDown to create a autocomplete popup when user type in a textbox. I want the popup is only displayed at bottom right of the textbox.
But when the textbox's position is near the right or bottom edge of the screen, popup will display at other position.
Can anyone help me?

Code in derived class from ToolStripDropDown:

```
public void Show(Presenters.IMainView c, Point position)
    {
        base.Show(c as Control, position, ToolStripDropDownDirection.BelowRight);
    }
```

Code in main view:

```
private void TextBoxAutocomplete_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _mPopup.Show((IMainView)this, ((TextBox)sender).Location);
    }
```

I want the popup behave like a normal form, which position is not restricted by screen or working area bounds, but not steal focus from parent form

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Edited and add more description

Comment: Finally, I came up with another workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use another and easier approach. Instead of using a derived class of ToolStripDropDown, I use a class derived from UserControl, make it not steal focus from it's parent (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143905/how-can-i-prevent-a-form-from-stealing-focus-while-still-receving-mouse-clicks))